# How can I stack LSTMs with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

This was asked a few times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331510/how-to-stack-multiple-lstm-in-keras) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510318/keras-stacking-multiple-lstm-layer-with) for instance).

My model is:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, VECTOR_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VECTOR_SIZE, activation='linear')))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Which works well.

When I try to stack it:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, VECTOR_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(32))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VECTOR_SIZE, activation='linear')))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_tf.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_tf.py", line 89, in main
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VECTOR_SIZE, activation='linear')))
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/pytorch-lstm-audio-Pq4zK81J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 182, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/pytorch-lstm-audio-Pq4zK81J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/pytorch-lstm-audio-Pq4zK81J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/pytorch-lstm-audio-Pq4zK81J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 197, in build
    assert len(input_shape) >= 3
AssertionError
```

The previous answers seem to make it seem so easy, but the reality is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `return_sequences=True`for all recurrent layers in the stack, except the last one, so in your example you should do:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, VECTOR_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VECTOR_SIZE, activation='linear')))
```